# Looping through parameter values in Cruisecontrol.net

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have setup a Cruisecontrol build for my project, which I need to run for multiple environments. This is what I currently use:

```
<parameters>
    <selectParameter>
        <name>Environment1</name>
        <display>Environment1</display>
        <allowedValues>
            <value name="No">No</value>
        <value name="Yes">Yes</value>
        </allowedValues>
    </selectParameter>
    <selectParameter>
        <name>Environment2</name>
        <display>Environment2</display>
        <allowedValues>
            <value name="No">No</value>
        <value name="Yes">Yes</value>
        </allowedValues>
    </selectParameter>
    <selectParameter>
        <name>Environment3</name>
        <display>Environment3</display>
        <allowedValues>
            <value name="No">No</value>
        <value name="Yes">Yes</value>
        </allowedValues>
    </selectParameter>
</parameters>

<conditional>
    <conditions>
    <compareCondition value1="Environment1" evaluation="equal" value2="Yes" />
    </conditions>
    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>$[DirectoryOfBuildScript]</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>MSBuild.proj</projectFile>
            <buildArgs>/v:n /p:Environment=Environment1;Version=$[BuildVersion];</buildArgs>
            <targets>Deploy</targets>
            <timeout>3000</timeout>
            <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\bin\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
    </tasks>
</conditional>

<conditional>
    <conditions>
    <compareCondition value1="Environment2" evaluation="equal" value2="Yes" />
    </conditions>
    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>$[DirectoryOfBuildScript]</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>MSBuild.proj</projectFile>
            <buildArgs>/v:n /p:Environment=Environment2;Version=$[BuildVersion];</buildArgs>
            <targets>Deploy</targets>
            <timeout>3000</timeout>
            <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\bin\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
    </tasks>
</conditional>

<conditional>
    <conditions>
    <compareCondition value1="Environment3" evaluation="equal" value2="Yes" />
    </conditions>
    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>$[DirectoryOfBuildScript]</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>MSBuild.proj</projectFile>
            <buildArgs>/v:n /p:Environment=Environment3;Version=$[BuildVersion];</buildArgs>
            <targets>Deploy</targets>
            <timeout>3000</timeout>
            <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\bin\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
    </tasks>
</conditional>
```

As you can see, only the Environment name differs in all the conditional statements. Is there any way so that I generalize my build call here by looping the selected Environment names (Versions will not differ). Something like this:

```
// Conceptually I want a for loop which iterates through the selected environments
foreach(environmentName in selectedEnvironments)
{
    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>$[DirectoryOfBuildScript]</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>MSBuild.proj</projectFile>
            <buildArgs>/v:n /p:Environment=environmentName;Version=$[BuildVersion];</buildArgs>
            <targets>Deploy</targets>
            <timeout>3000</timeout>
            <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\bin\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
    </tasks>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using preprocessor for this stuff. It seems there is for-each element in preprocessor, though I don't see it documented anywhere. But there are tests in CCNet sources that show how to use it.

Regarding the question, I created a similar proof of concept, I think you should be able to easily adapt it to your conditions. Instead of building certain environments, I just provide the list of domains to ping.

Provide the domains as *define*, in order not to repeat it twice or more:

```
<cb:define name="domains">
    ['facebook', 'twitter', 'wired']
</cb:define>
```

Then in the same fashion define parameter:

```
<cb:define name="paramDef">
    <selectParameter>
        <name>$(domainName)</name>
        <display>$(domainName)</display>
        <allowedValues>
            <value name="No">No</value>
            <value name="Yes">Yes</value>
        </allowedValues>
    </selectParameter>
</cb:define>
```

...and for tasks:

```
<cb:define name="condTask">         
    <conditional>
        <conditions>
            <compareCondition>
                <value1>$[$(domainName)]</value1>
                <value2>Yes</value2>
                <evaluation>Equal</evaluation>
                <ignoreCase>true</ignoreCase>
            </compareCondition>
        </conditions>
        <tasks>
            <exec executable="ping">
                <buildArgs>$(domainName).com</buildArgs>
            </exec>
        </tasks>
    </conditional>
</cb:define>
```

(Note the weird construct in *value1* - it matches the name and then evaluates value for that name)

And now we have everything in place, so we can just generate what we need.
For parameters:

```
<parameters>
    <cb:for-each iterator-name="i" iterator-expr="$(domains)">
        <cb:scope domainName="$(i)">    
            <cb:paramDef />
        </cb:scope>
    </cb:for-each>
</parameters>
```

...and the same for tasks:

```
<tasks>
    <cb:for-each iterator-name="i" iterator-expr="$(domains)">
        <cb:scope domainName="$(i)">    
            <cb:condTask />
        </cb:scope>
    </cb:for-each>
</tasks>
```

And that's it. Next domain I need to ping requires just to put it into *domains* array.

Some notes:

- the *cb:scope* element overrides the actually defined value.
- in case above, where values required are in the form Environment1, Environment2, Environment3 and so forth, it might be a little bit easier to use regular *for* loop of preprocessor (sample in documentation)
- Documentation for preprocessor: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor